# CallOut popup doesn't position itself with zoom in/out

Tags: android, arcgis, esri

I have an Arcgis map with pins.When i tap on a pin i am showing a callout(popover)over the pins which works perfectly fine.But when i zoom in/out the map, callout does't position itself with  respect to the pin on the map.How can i always show callout on top of pin while zooming in/out.

tap on pin and callout pops up
[image]

and the image where pop up moves away from pin when zoom in
[image]

Note: I have made changes to the existing sample project of Arcgis map app i.e. [SymbolizingResults](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=f97fbeaf044a4509bc9d2f988b8b0f64)

Here are the changes i have made to the SymbolizingResults Activity

```
public class SymbolizingResults extends Activity {

MapView map;
Button queryBtn;
GraphicsLayer gl;
Callout callout;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
    map.addLayer(new ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer(
            "http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer"));

    gl = new GraphicsLayer();
    gl.setRenderer(createClassBreaksRenderer());
    Point p = new Point(37.6922222, -97.3372222);
    HashMap<String, Object> map1 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map1.put("NAME", "India");
    PictureMarkerSymbol pic = new PictureMarkerSymbol(this,getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pin_dest));
    Graphic gr = new Graphic(p,pic,map1);
    gl.addGraphic(gr);
    map.addLayer(gl);
    queryBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.querybtn);

    queryBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Sets query parameter
            Query query = new Query();
            query.setWhere("STATE_NAME='Kansas'");

            query.setReturnGeometry(true);
            String[] outfields = new String[] { "NAME", "STATE_NAME",
                    "POP07_SQMI" };
            query.setOutFields(outfields);
            query.setOutSpatialReference(map.getSpatialReference());

            Query[] queryParams = { query };

            AsyncQueryTask qt = new AsyncQueryTask();

            qt.execute(queryParams);

        }
    });

    // Sets 'OnSingleTapListener' so that when single tap
    // happens, Callout would show 'SQMI' information associated
    // with tapped 'Graphic'
    map.setOnSingleTapListener(new OnSingleTapListener() {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public void onSingleTap(float x, float y) {


            if (!map.isLoaded())
                return;

            Point toDroppedPinPoint = map.toMapPoint(x, y);
            System.out.println("X : "+toDroppedPinPoint.getX());
            System.out.println("Y : "+toDroppedPinPoint.getY());

            int[] uids = gl.getGraphicIDs(x, y, 2);
            if (uids != null && uids.length > 0) {

                int targetId = uids[0];
                Graphic gr = gl.getGraphic(targetId);
                callout = map.getCallout();

                // Sets Callout style
                callout.setStyle(R.xml.countypop);
               /* String countyName = (String) gr.getAttributeValue("NAME");
                String countyPop = gr.getAttributeValue("POP07_SQMI")
                        .toString();*/
                // Sets custom content view to Callout
                callout.setContent(loadView("Anshul", "India"));
                callout.show(map.toMapPoint(new Point(x, y)));
            } else {
                if (callout != null && callout.isShowing()) {
                    callout.hide();
                }
            }

        }
    });

}

// Creates custom content view with 'Graphic' attributes
private View loadView(String countyName, String pop07) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(CalloutSampleActivity.this).inflate(
            R.layout.sqmi, null);

    final TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.county_name);
    name.setText(countyName + "'s SQMI");

    final TextView number = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pop_sqmi);
    number.setText(pop07);

    final ImageView photo = (ImageView) view
            .findViewById(R.id.family_photo);
    photo.setImageDrawable(CalloutSampleActivity.this.getResources()
            .getDrawable(R.drawable.family));

    return view;

}`
```

Answer (score 1):

The trouble is this line:

```
callout.show(map.toMapPoint(new Point(x, y)));
```

Here you're saying you want to show the callout at the point that the user tapped. That's what the sample does, and in the sample it always makes sense because the sample's graphics are all polygons (i.e. counties in Kansas).

But for a point, like the pin you added, you don't want to show the callout at the tapped point. If the tapped point is a couple of pixels away from the pin, and then you zoom out, the difference can be hundreds of miles! Instead, you want to show the callout at the pin graphic's point. But you only want to do that if it's actually a point, so you need to check the graphic's geometry with `instanceof`.

I replaced the above line with this and it works:

```
Geometry graphicGeom = gr.getGeometry();
if (graphicGeom instanceof Point) {
    callout.show((Point) graphicGeom);
} else {
    callout.show(toDroppedPinPoint);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot gary. My 50 points is yours.Please help me in this also
http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/99699-Callout.isShowing-returns-false-even-if-callout-is-visible?p=354260#post354260

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't see the code about how you are zooming in & out. But logically you should update the callout position in zoom-in & zoom-out too like you are doing in onSingleTap().

Comment: This is the example code from Arcgis in which i have made changes.But the logic to update the callout on zoom in/out also i have tried but no luck.